# Get value from customer_entity_varchar - Magento

Tags: sql, database, magento, orm

I created a customer attribute in backend magento, but I want to show this attribute to the user so that he can alter its value in the frontend. My input field is being displayed in the frontend, but the value is not there. I am not able to get this value. I found that the value that I need to display is in the apscustomer_entity_varchar table and the column is called 'value'. How can I get that value from that table? I was trying this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $data) {
  return $data;
}
```

but it was not working, so I used SQL code and it worked. However I know that's not a nice way to do that in Magento. What I did was something like:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM `apscustomer_entity_varchar ` WHERE `entity_id`='$id'";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

How can I get the value column from my apscustomer_entity_varchar table in the magento way, using the getModel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the customer of the session and then you can get the attribute you want :

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData('attributeName');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getAttributeName(); //Magic getter
```

Where attributeName is the name of the attribute you want to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do that :D

It's actually very simple. Even if this is a custom customer attribute (created in Magento admin panel), I need to get the attribute not using the 'eav/entity_attribute' model, but using the 'customer/customer' model. So I just need to do that:

```
$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id)->getData();
echo $customer_data['attributeThatYouWant'];
```

If you are not sure what is the name of your attribute you can look at Magento Admin Panel under Customer/Manage-Attributes, or you can use that after getting the model:

```
var_dump($customer_data);
```

Now you are able to get the name of all customer attributes.